# Buildr workspace dependency

Tags: buildr

I have two projects, project A and project B. Project A is a library project, so it has its own buildfile. I can build jar and everything works fine.

In project B i want to use project A as a workspace dependency in Eclipse. I don't wan't to install project A to local repo each time i make changes in project A.
Also when i run buildr eclipse i want it to setup my eclipse project so it adds project A as required project on build path:

```
<classpathentry combineaccessrules="false" kind="src" path="/A"/>
```

It should work as:

```
compile.with project('A')
```

But my project A is in different buildfile as project B.

Is there a way to setup workspace dependency on project A in buildfile for project B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no practical way to achieve that at this time. Dependencies between different buildfiles cannot be resolved as the projects are organized with a top level for each Buildfile.

If you'd like to take this further, please feel free to file an enhancement request on the Apache buildr bug tracking system and provide a patch. Even just a spec would help a ton.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I used Gradle meanwhile. Buildr was nice, but i had problems with Ruby. Groovy was easier to snap on for me.